# Need to convert the sql query as per snowflake standards

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
IF DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())=2       
BEGIN      
 SET @VAL = MARS.dbo.EDS_DT(DATEADD(dd,0,GETDATE())) --**0      
 SET @VAL1 = MARS.dbo.EDS_DT(DATEADD(dd,-4,GETDATE())) --**-4      
END      
      
IF DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())>2      
BEGIN      
 SET @VAL = MARS.dbo.EDS_DT(DATEADD(dd,0,GETDATE())) --**0      
 SET @VAL1 = MARS.dbo.EDS_DT(DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE())) --**-2      
END
```

I am getting this error

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 5 unexpected 'SELECT'. syntax error line 2 at position 16 unexpected '.'.

Please help with this

Comment: As there is no SELECT in the code you’ve given I’m not sure how the code relates to the error message? Is there more code that you haven’t shown?

Comment: Here using select to call function EDS_DT

Comment: Hi - you probably need to update your question with the full SQL statement in order for anyone to help you

Comment: I have to apply the logic after this                                                                    
FROM MARS.MARS_CSRM.ACA00PDLIB_RETPHY01
WHERE substr(REASON_CODE_RACH,1,1)<>'C' AND LOG_DATE=---VAL---- 

FROM MARS.MARS_CSRM.ACA00PDLIB_RCHPHY01
WHERE substring(AGENT_IDENTIFIER,1,3) ='ACN' AND LOG_DATE> ---VAL1-